# Syntax error when trying to pipe multiple commands in an alias definition

Tags: linux, bash

Hey can anyone help me to solve syntax error on creation of `alias`.I am new to bash so i am not aware of any restriction in use of `alias` command

Every time i run this `alias` command

```
alias user='responseVar=$(curl -XGET link)  && echo ${responseVar} | jq '.offsets[] | " \(.topic) \(.offset) \(.logSize) "' | awk 'NR>1{arr[$2]=arr[$2]+($4-$3)} END{for (a in arr) print a"="arr[a]}''
```

I get this error.

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: On what planet is that a simple alias command?

Comment: What is this code doing that you need `awk` for? (I'd be rather surprised if all the logic couldn't be moved into `jq`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `alias` (they're only allowed in interactive shells) and define a simple function instead to do

```
doSomething() {
    curl -XGET link | jq '.offsets[] | " \(.topic) \(.offset) \(.logSize) "' |
       awk 'NR>1{arr[$2]=arr[$2]+($4-$3)} END{for (a in arr) print a"="arr[a]}'
}
```

and defined in any of your startup configuration files(e.g. `.bashrc` for instance) and launch and new shell and do just

```
doSomething
```